# Ошибка подключения библиотеки material-dialogs

Tags: android-studio, android

При попытке подключить [material-dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)  библиотеку выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[после исправления выдало ошибку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4vKD.png)
[image: что исправил]

[image: пишет гдето здесь ошибка]
пишет что гдето тут ошибка непойму

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whitestar.successstudent"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

//materialDialogs
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/headerbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: ошибку лучше текстом писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
//materialDialogs
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

//materialDialogs
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Comment: помогите ... посмотрите скиншоты плс

Comment: пожалуйста там новая ошибка(((

Comment: См. обновённый ответ. IDE ругается из-за несоответствия версий библиотеки диалогов и библиотеки поддержки

Comment: изменил на последнюю версию не помогло((((

Comment: А **buildTools** у вас последней, совпадающей версии? `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: кажется да, сейчас скрин залью

Comment: @Андрей, не надо скринов, приводите текст. Скринами - аццки неудобно.

Comment: да сдк толс 23 + 24 и 22 установлены , помогите пожалуйста @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Приведите в вопросе текстом ваш gradle файл целиком.

Comment: Не-не-не, так ещё менее удобно чем скрином... Нажмите `править` под вашим вопросом и добавьте текст туда)

Comment: А так да - у вас `buildToolsVersion` не тот. Проставьте **23.0.1**

Comment: И `compileSdkVersion` также на 23 замените.

Comment: спасибо огромное, заработало , никогда не забуду твою доброту))) )))))))))@ЮрийСП

Comment: Пожалуйста) И добро пожаловать на ru-SO)

Comment: ахахаахха сам не ожидал но я вернулся, ошибок нет но приложение не запускается@ЮрийСП при запуске на емуляторе ввыдает ошибку в майн активити seContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Без stackTrace ошибки понять почему не запускается - нельзя. Если билдится нормально, то ошибка не в подключении библиотеки и мой ответ - верный. В этом случае вам надо создать новый вопрос.

Comment: ок буду постить

Comment: У вас, видимо, проблема в разметке - создайте новый вопрос с подробной информацией. И попробуйте ещё  `targetSdkVersion` на 23 установить

Comment: я добавил разметку посмотрите @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Разметка выглядит нормально. Если приложение падает во время исполнения - значит библиотека подключена правильно. Вам надо создать новый вопрос (а не редактировать/дополнять этот). В коем описать проблему. При этом можно в новом вопросе дать ссылку на этот.

Comment: спасибо))))))))

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30776/discussion-on-answer-by-----material-dialogs).