# Не запускается приложение setContentView(); java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features

Tags: android-studio, android, activity

Ошибок в андроид студио нет, только когда запускаеш приложение на емуляторе.
[преддыдущий пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461432/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-material-dialogs) -  где я подключал материал - диалог. Чистел и ребилдел - непомогло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whitestar.successstudent"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

//materialDialogs
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/headerbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Строка с ошибками:

```
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whitestar.successstudent/com.whitestar.successstudent.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:423)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:254)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.whitestar.successstudent.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
10-26 23:08:58.744 14019-14019/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-26 23:10:48.980 14019-14023/com.whitestar.successstudent D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 255K, 9% free 8141K/8903K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 6ms
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>

        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Строчки внизу скриншота - это `StackTrace` с подробной инфой об ошибке. Выложите их целиком текстом.

Comment: выложил @ЮрийСПб

Comment: ребята помогите оч прошу))

Comment: Проблема в темах. Посмотрите ответы тут (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614064/appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme-features-nothing-works) и тут (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat) и тут (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784124/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme). Если не поможет - запостите содержимое `styles.xml` в вопрос.

Comment: щас запостю только не ухадите, а то я до утра буду тут сидеть @ЮрийСПб

Comment: вы мне уже 2 раз  помогли как я могу вас отблагодарить?@ЮрийСПб

Comment: этот сайт самый лучший для новичков розроботчиков как я спасибо Юрию и сайту, все все понял иду учить русский xDDDDD @ЮрийСПб

Comment: проблема была в стилях!! СПАСИБО

Comment: Комп уже выключен, с телефона помочь не смогу. Чрез пять часов вставать на работу) в стактрасе у вас написано на какие атрибуты темы ругается приложение. Поиграйтесь с ними или установите приложению тему стандартную. Ту что в parent в styles.xml написано. А отблагодарить можно плюсами за вопросы ответы на сайте и отвечанием на вопросы и задаванием хороших вопросов. В справке по сайту всё это подробно написано. Спокойной ночи)

Comment: Если вы разобрались в чём проблема-напишите об этом в ответе. Это поможет будущим посетителям сайта, а вам даст очки репутации, кои бывают очень полезны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это известные грабли. Надо задать в манифесте свою тему для вашей активити:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme">
```

А в стилях задекларировать:

```
<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

где `AppTheme` - стиль приложения.

Связано с отсутствием в `AppCompat` соответствующих стилей, так что их придется декларировать самим. Возможно потребуется еще декларировать и остальные свойства указанные в логе:

```
AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { 
   windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, 
   android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, 
   windowNoTitle: false 
}
```